# getting "org.apache.http.nohttpresponseexception the target server failed to respond" while calling wso2 http endpoint

Tags: http, wso2

I am getting below error while calling http endpoint:-
The endpoint is HTTP endpoint which I am using.
Also added timeout parameters in axis2.xml and axis2.blocking.xml.
But it did not work.
Can anyone provide any solution to it?

```
HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://*********]
org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException: The server ****** failed to respond
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1976)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
```

the esb proxy looks like below:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="mqListener"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log description="print message" level="full">
            <property name="message" value="&#34;In listenAbc1Mq&#34;"/>
         </log>
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
      {
"orderId": ""
}
    </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//verkkopvc/text()"/>
</payloadFactory>
         <log description="print message" level="full">
            <property name="message" value="&#34;after payload factory&#34;"/>
         </log>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="true"/>
         <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint key="abc"/>
         </call>
         <log description="print message" level="full">
            <property name="message" value="&#34;Out sequence&#34;"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is printed by your http client. To fix it, do these.

1) Remove `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>`

2) Add `<respond/>` mediator at the end of `inSequence`.